# In PowerShell how do I correctly match exit codes?

Tags: powershell

I'm modifying someone else's script to update various BIOS versions.  The updates can trigger a number of different exit codes, so the original author had the exit code conditions setup like this:

```
if ($FlashProcess.ExitCode -match "0|2|6|3010")
```

However, I noticed that if I received a code such as "1602" it would still match because of the "0" or "2" or "6" in "1602".  How do I prevent that from happening?  I realize I could do a "-like -and" for each code number, but thought there might be a shorter method.

Comment: Anchor your regular expression: `$FlashProcess.ExitCode -match '^(0|2|6|3010)$'`. Or don't use a regular expression in the first place: `0, 2, 6, 3010 -contains $FlashProcess.ExitCode`.

Comment: The anchor expression method is the most useful to me and it's working great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExitCode` is an `int` property:

`ExitCode                   Property       int ExitCode {get;}`

Therefore, the best way is to us `-in` condition operator:

`if ($FlashProcess.ExitCode -in @(0, 2, 6, 3010))`

Comment: Note that `-in` is not available prior to PowerShell v3. If you need (or want) compatibility with earlier versions use `<list> -contains <value>` instead of `<value> -in <list>`.